# How to do SSO with Django and ReactJS?

Tags: django, reactjs, single-sign-on, siteminder

I need to bootstrap a Django application with ReactJS. Authentication needs to work through Siteminder (SSO). How can ReactJS components know what user is authenticated? What are the common techniques for client side components to know the authenticated user, if any?

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by using "authentication backends" available in Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#other-authentication-sources

You might have to make calls to API provided by your SSO provider to do a complete integration.